# Scala class file vs Java class file

Tags: java, scala, distribution

Let's say I have this Hello.scala.

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

I could run 'scalac' to get HelloWorld.class and HelloWorld$.class.
I can run using 'scala -classpath . Hello'. But I can't run 'java -cp . Hello'.

- Why is this? Isn't scala interoperable with Java?
- Is there any way to run scala's class with Java?
- Why the scalac produces two class files?
- Does scala have something like 'lein uber'? I mean, does scala have some tools that generates one jar file for distribution purposes?

### IntelliJ + scala plugin

I could get a jar that contains everything to run scala file file with IntelliJ + scala plugin, I think this is the better option than proguard.

### proguard setup

Thanks to Moritz, I could make one jar file that be run with java.
This is the overall structure.

```
|-- classes
|   |-- HelloWorld$.class
|   |-- HelloWorld.class
|   `-- META-INF
|       `-- MANIFEST.MF
`-- your.pro
```

your.pro has the following contents.

```
-injar classes
-injar /Users/smcho/bin/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-outjar main.jar
-libraryjar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Classes/classes.jar

-dontwarn
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings

-optimizationpasses 2
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable

-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking class * { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclasseswithmembers public class HelloWorld { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
```

MANIFEST.MF has following setup. Don't forget to include [CR] or blank line.

```
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

I download the proguard 4.5.1 to put it in ~/bin/proguard4.5.1.
Running proguard, I could make the jar (main.jar), and it works fine.

```
prosseek:classes smcho$ java -Xmx512m -jar /Users/smcho/bin/proguard4.5.1/lib/proguard.jar @your.pro

ProGuard, version 4.5.1
Reading program directory [/Users/smcho/Desktop/scala/proguard/classes/classes]
Reading program jar [/Users/smcho/bin/scala/lib/scala-library.jar] (filtered)
Reading library jar [/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar]
Preparing output jar [/Users/smcho/Desktop/scala/proguard/classes/main.jar]
  Copying resources from program directory [/Users/smcho/Desktop/scala/proguard/classes/classes]
  Copying resources from program jar [/Users/smcho/bin/scala/lib/scala-library.jar] (filtered)
```

```
prosseek:classes smcho$ java -jar main.jar hello
```

or

`java -cp main.jar HelloWorld`

I upload the example zip file [here](http://web.me.com/sm.cho/filechute/classes.zip). And, scalar source code [here](http://web.me.com/sm.cho/filechute/hello.scala).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add Scala to the classpath, e.g.

```
-classpath scala-library.jar:.
```

or by adding

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:scala-library.jar
```

to the VM arguments.

**Addition:**

Sorry, did not see that last question. If you want do distribute single JAR files many people use [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to ship the classes needed from the scala-library.jar along with your classes in one jar.

**Second Edit:**

Assuming you have your .class-files and your `META-INF` folder containing the `MANIFEST.MF` in a folder called classes you can use the following Proguard configuration (after adjusting the paths, e.g. you need `rt.jar` on Linux/Windows instead of `classes.jar` on Mac OS) saved e.g. as `your.pro`:

```
-injar classes
-injar /opt/local/share/scala-2.8/lib/scala-library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)
-outjar main.jar
-libraryjar /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Classes/classes.jar

-dontwarn
-dontnote
-ignorewarnings

-optimizationpasses 2
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable

-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking class * { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclasseswithmembers public class your.Main { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
```

Now you can create `main.jar` with

```
java -Xmx512m -jar proguard.jar @your.pro
```

Eventually you have to set the `-Xmx` a bit higher. Some more info can be found on the [SBT Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/ProGuard).

Comment: @Moritz : Thanks for the answer, and I could run scala class with Java. But for making one jar file, could you give me some example how to do that? It seems that I have to make jar out of class first to make one big jar. Is this correct?

Comment: @prosseek updated that. Although the name of the parameter is "-injar"  Proguard actually also accepts a directory as input

Comment: @Moritz : I tested by following your answer, but I couldn't get main.jar. Could you check that?

Comment: @prosseek you have two errors in your setup: first you have to replace `your.Main` with `HelloWorld` in your.pro and second you have to copy the META-INF folder to classes if you want it to be included in the resulting jar.

Comment: @Moritz : I could make the jar, but it doesn't seem to work. Could you check that once more? I uploaded the example files also.

Comment: @prosseek: your `MANIFEST.MF` is not valid: every line has to be terminated by a newline and you are missing the line `Manifest-Version: 1.0` (though it should work without that line - but I would add it). Fixing that I could build and run the jar from the files you supplied.

Comment: Typo: `booclasspath`? Boo! ;-) Should be `bootclasspath`.